# Autoincrement month automatically rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

I want to do current_month + `1.month` if statement true
for example

```
if condition #i mean true
 @month = Jan + 1.month #Feb
else
 current_month #Jan
end
```

first iteration starting month Jan next Feb ...etc

my problem is how to save updated @month for later use and increment it automatically

in short

i want to write method which takes argument and if its true updates month to next month automatically

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? What is the object in `@month` variable? And where you want to save it? in DB?

Comment: @month = Jan,it does not matter which month will be,ye in db

Comment: What is `Jan`? a String: "Jan"?, date object?, or datetime object? is it a column in a table of a model class?

Comment: @month - which type of object is that?

Comment: hey, how the going with the issue?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko i did .. simply save start date to db and if condition true updating start date + 1.month

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Date` stored in `@month`:

```
@month += 1.month if condition
```

If `condition` is evaluated to `true` then add one month. Otherwise leave `@month` as it is.

Is that what you want?